# Why does the selector inside useSelector run twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, render

Why does the selector inside useSelector run twice?

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-architecture-60hcu)

```
const selector = (state) => {
  console.log("invoke Selector");

  return state;
};

function App() {
  console.log("render App");

  const count = useSelector(selector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })}>Decrement</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Here is a working snippet showing the selector callback is run twice every time Child mounts:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

function count(state, action) {
  console.log('reducing action:',action.type)
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {...state,count:state.count+1};
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {...state,count:state.count-1};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(count,{count:0});

const selector = (state) => {
  console.log("invoke Selector",state);

  return state.count;
};

function Child() {
  console.log("render Child");

  const count = useSelector(selector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })}>Decrement</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
const App = () => {
  const [show,setShow] = React.useState(true);

  return (<div>
    <button onClick={()=>setShow(s=>!s)}>toggle child</button>
    {show?<Child />:'none'}
  </div>)
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem if used correctly. Are you asking out of curiosity or do you have an actual issue related to this behavior? (XY problem)

Comment: @idmean out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it runs both in the render phase, and after an action is dispatched.  So, the first log happens when `<App>` is rendered, and the second log happens when you click the button and dispatch an action that updates the store state.

`useSelector` also re-runs the selector a second time after the component has mounted, to check if there are any other changes due to actions being dispatched while the component tree was being constructed.

Comment: I don't know why the first time load app, selector also run twice.

Comment: Because [React double-renders components in `<StrictMode>`](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-behavior-edge-cases).

Comment: But after all, when rendering, there is a double display to the console

Comment: Also I removed the <StrictMode> wrapper in example

Comment: @markerikson I did notice selector callback running more often than expected. The [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-architecture-60hcu?file=/src/index.js) has no strict mode and when it loads it'll render app only to run the callback twice without any actions being dispatched (init was dispatched before App ran). I always thought that callbacks only run on mount and whenever an action returns new state but the example shows a different behaviour.

Comment: Updated - `useSelector` runs a second check after it mounts.

Comment: @markerikson Do I understand correctly that the "reselect" library removes this behavior?

Comment: No. We're talking about when and why `useSelector` calls `selector(state)`. The description here applies regardless of how that selector function is implemented.  Reselect is just one way to implement a selector function.

Comment: @cuongdevjs, the 1st run is when <App> is rendered, the 2nd run is  after the component has mounted, to check if there are any other changes due to actions being dispatched while the component tree was being constructed